# Updating the value of other column while insertion in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My task is pretty much simple let's say I have table having 3 columns i.e. temp(ids, name_c, UID_c) and I have first two column values and 3rd column is nullable. What I want to do is whenever these two value is inserted the value of third column must be updated (after insertion) with new value. i.e concatenation of both values.

For Ex.

```
 insert into temp(ids, name_c) values(did.nextval,'Andrew');
```

The result should be

```
     1         Andrew           Andrew_1
```

So I am using trigger for this purpose

```
  create or replace trigger triggerDemo
  after INSERT
  on temp
  for each row
  declare  
  /*    pragma autonomous_transaction;*/
     user_name varchar2(50);
     current_val number;
  begin    
    select did.currval into current_val from dual; /* did is sequence */
    select names into user_name from temp where ids = current_val;
    update temp set uid_c = user_name||'_'||ids where ids = current_val;
    end;
```

When I am inserting the values I get this error

```
  01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
  *Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
  *Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want a `before insert` trigger, not an `after insert` trigger.  Second, decide whether you want to calculate the `id` on input or in the trigger.  You can do something like this:

```
create or replace trigger triggerDemo before INSERT on temp
for each row
  /*    pragma autonomous_transaction;*/
begin  
    if :new.current_val is null then  
        select did.currval into :new.ids from dual; /* did is sequence */
    end;
    select :new.user_name || '_' || :new.ids into :new.uid_c from dual;
end;
```